# How to create thumbnails in R?

Tags: r, thumbnails, plot

I am trying to produce a `.png` file with an R plot. This works great:

```
png(file="hello.png", width=1000, height=800)

# Lots and lots of plotting. Long code. Very slow.
plot(x=c(1, 2, 3), y=c(4, 6, 5))

dev.off()
```

Now how can I get a thumbnail of `hello.png` directly from R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how this will scale to your real application and don't have much experience with the `png` library, but this worked reasonably quick on my test cases. You need to specify the name of the PNG file you want to make a thumbnail of and the height / width of that thumbnail. By default, it will save a thumbnail in the same directory with `thumb_` prepended to the file name.

```
makeThumb <- function(file, height, width) {
  require(png)
  img <- readPNG(file)

  png(file = paste("thumb", file, sep = "_"), height = height, width = width)
    par(mar=c(0,0,0,0), xaxs="i", yaxs="i", ann=FALSE)
    plot(1:2, type='n', xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
    lim <- par()
    rasterImage(img, lim$usr[1], lim$usr[3], lim$usr[2], lim$usr[4])
  dev.off()
}
```

Let me know if this works for you. The function works well with `lapply` to operate on a large number of files in a directory at once as well: `lapply(listOfFiles, makeThumb, height = 200, width = 200)`.

Comment: [rimage](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rimage/index.html) looks like it provides equivalent read functionality for jpegs should that be needed.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to install the png library right now to see how that worked!

Comment: Hmm, I am getting "Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large" - working on it now.

Comment: @Roman - It took me a bit to get the examples in the help documentation to work properly, and honestly don't really know what I did to get it to behave properly. Have you tried running any of the examples in the help docs? Sorry I'm not more help there...I'll spend some more time with it later tonight and let you know if I uncover anything enlightening.

Comment: @Chase: I am trying to make a very small (100 x 100) thumbnail. The standard plotting functions are trying to use margins around the plotting area. I am trying to figure out how to plot over the entire area of the bitmap, without any margin.

Comment: @Roman - hmm, I wonder if setting the `mar` to zero would fix it. Another option looks to be the EBImage package from Bioconductor that connects ImageMagick to R. Haven't used it, but I'm guessing it's cropping capabilities will be superior than the hack job above: http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/EBImage.html

Comment: @Chase I was kind of hoping to keep the package dependencies to minimum. With ImageMagick, I could just install standalone ImageMagick and do the extra processing by calling it from a script.

Comment: I arrived at this: `par(mar=c(0,0,0,0), xaxs="i", yaxs="i", ann=FALSE)` - the key is xaxs="i" and yaxs="i" to remove the "internal margin". Can you modify your code to involve this?

Comment: @Roman - edited code to reflect your changes. I tested on a directory with 70 images making 100 x 100 thumbnails of all images with no errors. Code ran in a little less than 10 seconds (windows 7, 64 bit, 8 gig ram machine) so was pretty happy with that. Hope this works for you!

Comment: I am accepting this answer - the other approaches would work as well, but this was the most readily available solution that did not invoke the plotting functions twice, did not create a large log from the graphics commands, and dealt correctly with the broken margins.

Answer (score 2):

You could just write the plot to file twice, with different sizes.

```
#wrap your plotting code into a function
my_plot <- function()
{
  #whatever
}

plot_file_name <- "hello.png"
png(file = plot_file_name, width = 1000, height = 800)
my_plot()
dev.off()

png(file = paste("thumb", plot_file_name, sep = "_"), width = 40, height = 32)
my_plot()
dev.off()
```

This technique works better with `lattice` or `ggplot2`, where `my_plot` can return a plot object, so you don't need to call the function twice, i.e, you call

```
a_plot <- myplot()
png(...)
print(a_plot)
dev.off()
```

EDIT:  There are several different ways of "zooming".  Here's a ggplot2 workflow example.

Draw and save your plot

```
myplot <- function()
{
  #e.g.,
  ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point()
}

the_plot <- myplot()

ggsave("full plot.png", the_plot)
```

You probably want to update the geom sizes to be smaller

```
scale_factor <- 0.1
update_geom_defaults("point", aes(size = 2 * scale_factor))
```

You can use `opts_full` from the `ggExtra` package to only display the contents of the panel (i.e., to ignore the axes, titles and legend).

```
ggsave("thumbnail panel only.png", the_plot + opts_full(), scale = scale_factor)
```

The alternative is trying to reduce the size of the axes, etc.  Unfortunately, this is a bit of a pain to do.

```
theme_mini <- theme_grey(12 * scale_factor)
theme_mini$axis.ticks.length <- scale_factor * theme_mini$axis.ticks.length   
theme_mini$axis.ticks.margin <- scale_factor * theme_mini$axis.ticks.margin
theme_mini$panel.margin <- scale_factor * theme_mini$panel.margin 
theme_mini$plot.margin <- scale_factor * theme_mini$plot.margin
#and probably some more elements to resize

ggsave("thumbnail updated theme.png", the_plot + theme_mini, scale = scale_factor)
```

Comment: Hmm, I wanted to avoid this, since the plotting is quite involved to do twice. However, I would not get a perfect thumbnail this way, would I? I would need to set up some kind of zoom factor - how can I do that?

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I do not use ggplot right now - you are right, this is a pain. I will keep investigating this avenue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dev.copy` utility:

```
png("plot_large.png",1000,1000)
dev.control("enable")

# ..... start of plot section .....
plot(rnorm(100))
# ..... end of plot section .....

dev.copy(png, filename="plot_small.png", width=100, height=100)
dev.off()
dev.off()
```

You encounter the same problems like in [Chase answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504057/how-to-create-thumbnails-in-r/5504506#5504506), but here `par` parametrization influence **both plots**.

Second thing is note on `dev.copy` help page:

> Note that these functions copy the
>   device region and not a plot: the
>   background colour of the device
>   surface is part of what is copied.
>   Most screen devices default to a
>   transparent background, which is
>   probably not what is needed when
>   copying to a device such as png.

And third - this is not exactly thumbnail cause png size determine some parameters (which is why you got "figure margins too large" error). So personally I think you should use external image processing tool.

Comment: I will have to play with this a bit more to make it work - thank you for pointing me to this function!